# Can grid-row-gap / grip-column-gap be overridden for a single gutter?

Tags: css, css-grid

Is there a way to set a single `grid-row-gap` to specific size that is different from the rest of the grid?

Use case: the top row of the grid should have less of a gap to the second row than the rest of the grid as it acts as a header.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `grid-row-gap` and `grid-column-gap` properties apply to the entire grid ([spec reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#gutters)).

However, you can use negative margins on the second row grid items to adjust their position.

Another option would be to remove the top row (headers) from the current grid and place it in a different container directly above the data. This would eliminate the `grid-gap` problem.

Comment: Thanks, @Michael_B. This is what I thought as I read the spec and googled. Makes sense and the negative margins idea came to mind. For now, I'll just use two grids with the same column set. Seems cleaner.

Comment: For a row I'll need to add another flex div for the first element and wrap all of them with another flex div, seems hacky.