# Removing grid gaps

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a div with elements aligned as a row, this is the css class for it:

```css
.myRow {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.1fr 0.1fr 2fr 3fr 2fr;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myRow">
  <div style="color:blue; width: 5px;">aa</div>
  <div style="color:red;">bb</div>
  <div style="color:green;">ccc</div>
  <div style="color:orange;">ddd</div>
  <div style="color:purple;">eee</div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to remove the first two gaps and keep the rest of the gaps, like how `grid-template-columns` works.

[image]

Is it possible to do this with grid?

Edit: I want it to be like this:

[image]

Comment: See similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45151767/can-grid-row-gap-grip-column-gap-be-overridden-for-a-single-gutter

Comment: It's not exatcly the same, I want no gaps so the ccc, ddd, eee cells will take the space of those 2 first gaps. @sol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set multiple sizes for grid gaps. The [**`column-gap`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-gap) and [**`row-gap`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/row-gap) properties (previously `grid-column-gap` and `grid-row-gap`) accept only a single value.

This issue is covered in detail here:

- [Setting different lengths for grid gaps in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47461444/3597276)

---

Pseudo-elements applied to a grid container are considered grid items.

This behavior is explained here:

- [pseudo-element acting like a grid item in CSS grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45599317/3597276)

---

The [**`order`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property can be used to re-arrange grid items on the screen.

More details here:

- [Consider the `order` property of flex and grid layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36118012/3597276)

---

Taken in combination, you can create the column gaps – there are only two – with `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements, arrange their placement with the `order` property, and get rid of the `grid-column-gap` rule.

```css
.myRow {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.1fr 0.1fr 2fr auto 3fr auto 2fr;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.myRow::before {
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.myRow::after {
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.myRow > :nth-child(1) { order: -3; }
.myRow > :nth-child(2) { order: -2; }
.myRow > :nth-child(3) { order: -1; }
.myRow > :nth-child(5) { order: 1; }

.myRow > div {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="myRow">
  <div style="color:blue;">aa</div>
  <div style="color:red;">bb</div>
  <div style="color:green;">ccc</div>
  <div style="color:orange;">ddd</div>
  <div style="color:purple;">eee</div>
</div>
```

Here's a little more about how this works:

Since the default value of the `order` property is `0`, and items are then placed in source order, this is how the browser sees the `nth-child` pseudo-class code above:

```
.myRow > :nth-child(1) { order: -3; }
.myRow > :nth-child(2) { order: -2; }
.myRow > :nth-child(3) { order: -1; } /*
.myRow > ::before      { order: 0; }
.myRow > :nth-child(4) { order: 0; }
.myRow > ::after       { order: 0; } */
.myRow > :nth-child(5) { order: 1; }
```

Comment: Clever, but how come before and after are not applied to order < 0 though?

Comment: The before and after selectors aren't applied to the first 3 divs, why? (the before and after selectors are responsible for the gaps)

Comment: The `:nth-child()` selectors apply only to DOM elements. They ignore CSS elements. That's why I had to go around the pseudos.

Comment: I still don't understand... Why does the red square happen? https://i.imgur.com/gPc237o.png (The first 3 elements are in the DOM)

Answer (score 12):

Add **negative right margin** whose value is equal to grid gap

```css
.myRow {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.1fr 0.1fr 2fr 3fr 2fr;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.margin {
  margin-right: -10px
}
```

```html
<div class="myRow">
  <div class="margin" style="color:blue; width: 5px; ">aa</div>
  <div class="margin" style="color:red;">bb</div>
  <div style="color:green;">ccc</div>
  <div style="color:orange;">ddd</div>
  <div style="color:purple;">eee</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not what I wanted, I wanted the first 3 gaps between the cells to not be there, but the ccc cell is still in the same place.

Comment: @shinzou how is this not what you wanted? It matches your image for your desired result.

Comment: upvote for a clever simple solution, would not have thought this would work